# Is GIF image resolution fixed to 72ppi?

Tags: image, gif, imagemagick-convert

I dont understand the explanation about why GIF files always has image resolution 72ppi.

I have tried using ImageMagick converting PNG to GIF specifying `-density` to be 300ppi, but the resulting GIF is still 72ppi.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 72ppi GIF or a 300ppi PNG. See [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107892).

Comment: yeah the idea is ok, but usually when you open an image in photoshop or any photo editor, they usually show the image resolution. For JPEG, when I change its resolution to 300ppi, it show in the photo editor 300ppi. But for GIF image, I cannot changed it, its always showing 72ppi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GIF format does not store any value for *"ppi"* or *"dpi"* or pixel density/resolution - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF).

I think software assumes 72 dpi, and then loads your image, updating that assumption if it finds anything better... which it never will in the case of GIF.

---

In any case, the dpi/ppi is irrelevant until such time as you want to print your image, and I don't know of anyone ever using GIF as a method of submission of images to any reputable printers or publications - TIFF is probably the preferred or most common method.